# Scraping a script written in JS with BS4

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, aiohttp

I am currently working on a script that signs up for an account on a site using BS4 and aiohttp. One thing that is needed in the POST is something called tagInfo. Part of the tagInfo is this thing called "tmxSessionId". Normally I would have used BS4 like I normally do and scrape the value every time.  However the problem is that tmxSessionId is part of a script that is being used by the site and it is in JS. I will post a bit of the script here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {
var Context = raptor.require('ebay.context.Context');
    var langCode = "en-US";
    var emailAutoCompleteEnabled = true;

    var dfpContext = '{"tmxSessionId":"081708da1660ab61a9e69761fffcb25e"}';

}
```

I editied the script and removed most of all the extra bits provide a bit of context as well as the part that I'm curious about. So as you can see it is in a script tag. So as a test I tried to do

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
idd = soup.find('script', type='text/javascript')
```

it came back with `<script type="text/javascript">var layer = false;</script>`
and not the complete script. So how can I parse for tmxSessionId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through the same situation and found a shortcut by myself which helped me in every same scenario. You need to go for that shortcut.

```
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
your_script = [script for script in scripts if 'tmxSessionId' in str(script)][0]
print(your_script)
```

the list comprehension part will find the script element with the text you need. And mostly the first element will be your script. So I have added `[0]` in the end.

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: So in the future, lets say the script I don't want it the first one but the third one. I would do [0]? Also if it says script src, I should ignore that, since it it just the source and not the actual script that I need?

Comment: The key is not the index, you need to find the unique word from the `script ` element you need. Just iterate all the script elements and store the one you need with the key word. Happy that my suggestion helped you!

Comment: So like lets say that tmxSessionID is part of a really really large script that has a lot of unnecessary stuff in it that I don't need (I only need tmxSessionId). How would I only parse for that value? Is that not possible?